# Broadcast Receiver doesn't work

Tags: android

Main Activity Code. BroadcastExample.java

```
package com.example.broadcast;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class BroadcastExaple extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("PHONE", "Main Activity...Called");
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.d("PHONE", "After Mainf Activity...");
    }
}
```

MyBroadCastReceiver.java

```
package com.example.broadcast;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;


public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 /*public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  try{
  Log.d("Call BroadCAST","Calling Broad CAST");
  MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
  TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {

  }

 }*/
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       Log.d("Message", "Message Received");
    }


}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.broadcast" android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0">
 <uses-prmission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <activity android:name=".BroadcastExaple" android:label="@string/app_name">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
   </intent-filter>
   </receiver>

 </application>


 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

</manifest>
```

Program doesn't enter into the onReceive Mathod of MyBroadCastReceiver class.

Comment: have u registered the BR in the manifest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, i suggest you to format your code here. So that people here will be glad to read your problem code.
Your code list above does NOT register any BroadcastReceiver to the system. You'd better to check out ApiDemo for more details.

Comment: How can i register BroadcastReceiver to the System?

Comment: Here is some code i copied from ApiDemo:[pre] Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmController.this, OneShotAlarm.class); PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmController.this, 0, intent, 0); ... // Schedule the alarm! AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);<code>

Comment: Also, as someone mentioned before, you should put <receiver> in your manifest.xml